# Autofac when using IIndex<X,B> to resolve service throws exception

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, autofac

Итак, у нас есть два класса, реализующих интерфейс `IStateRepository`: `FileRepo` and `DBRepo` (реализация вне контекста). И класс-потребитель:

```
public class StateBase : IStateAdapter
{
     public StateBase(
         ILogger logger,
         SourceConfiguration source,
         StateConfiguration state,
         IIndex<StorageType, IStateRepository> repoService)
    {      
        _stateStorage = repoService[state.StorageType];
    }
}
```

Регистрация классов и их зависимостей:

```
var _builder = new ContainerBuilder();
_builder.RegisterInstance(_logger).As<ILogger>();
_builder.RegisterInstance(config.Source).As<SourceConfiguration>();
_builder.RegisterInstance(config.State).As<StateConfiguration>();
_builder.RegisterType<CsvFileRepository>().Keyed<IStateRepository>(StorageType.File)
    .UsingConstructor(typeof(ILogger), typeof(StateConfiguration));
_builder.RegisterType<MsSqlDataRepository>().Keyed<IStateRepository>(StorageType.Database)
// Register State Adapter
_builder.RegisterType<StateAsID>().Keyed<IStateAdapter>(StateType.ID);
_builder.RegisterType<StateAsRowVersion>().Keyed<IStateAdapter>(StateType.RowVersion);
_builder.RegisterType<StateAsTimeStamp>().Keyed<IStateAdapter>(StateType.TimeStamp);
_builder.RegisterType<StateAsFixedRange>().Keyed<IStateAdapter>(StateType.FixedRange);
```

Однако когда я пытаюсь отрезолвить реализацию `IStateAdapter`:

```
var state = _container.ResolveKeyed<IStateAdapter>(config.Source.LastStateType);
```

Падает следующий exception

> None of the constructors found with
>   'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type
>   'BI.Generic.PipeLine.StateAdapters.StateAsRowVersion' can be invoked
>   with the available services and parameters:\r\nCannot resolve
>   parameter
>   'Scalepoint.BI.Generic.Core.Interfaces.IIndex`2[BI.Generic.Core.StorageType,BI.Generic.PipeLine.StateAdapters.IStateRepository]
>   repoService' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Serilog.ILogger,
>   BI.Generic.Core.SourceConfiguration,
>   BI.Generic.Core.StateConfiguration,
>   BI.Generic.Core.Interfaces.IIndex`2[BI.Generic.Core.StorageType,BI.Generic.PipeLine.StateAdapters.IStateRepository])'.

Comment: А я вот что-то не нахожу в приведенном коде, где вы регистрирует интерфейс IStateAdapter, какой тип для вас DI контейнер должен для вас резолвить?

Comment: добавил этот код

Comment: Ну так а `IIndex<StorageType, IStateRepository>` у вас зарегистрирован?

Comment: @AlexeyGavrushenko НУ да, IIndex<StorageType, IStateRepositor> у вас не зарегистрирован в буилдере. Или опять не весь код регистрации?

Comment: Не зарегестрирован , а нужно ли это ж Интрефейс просто и у него нет инстансов.Если есть пример как это делать буду благодарен

Comment: А как по-вашему будет работать конструкция `repoService[state.StorageType]`, если никто не реализует интерфейс? Интерфейс -- это просто контракт, метаданные. А должна быть еще реализация, собственно сам код. Ну и да, все типы, которые перечислены в конструкторе типа, создающегося Автофаком, тоже должны быть зарегистрированы в Автофаке.